# Run unittest against installed packages

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm currently working on a project whose structure is:

```
my_package
│   README.md
|   setup.py
│
└───my_package
|   |   __init__.py
│   │   file1.py
│   │   file2.py
|   |   ...
│   └───subpackage
│       │   sub1.py
│       │   ...
│   
└───test
    |   __init__.py
    │   test_file1.py
    |   test_file2.py
```

I can run all my tests with `python -m unittest discover -s test`. Most of `test_x.py` files contain imports such as `from my_package.file1 import Something`. Hence, the `unittest` command will run all my tests against source code contained in `my_package`.

On the other hand, I created a private Pypi package from this package. In my CI, I would like to run my unit tests against **installed** files, rather than local source code.
`import my_package.file1; print(my_package.file1.__file__)` should then show a path to `site-packages`.

Is there a way to do so ?

Edit: I would like to keep my test folder separate from `my_package` folder as I do not intend to distribute my tests.

Answer (score 3):

To run discovery-tests against installed package do next thing:

Inside your package's directory `./test/` add file `run.py` with the following content:

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow66651858#main.py)

```
import os, unittest

def load_tests(loader, standard_tests, pattern):
    this_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    pattern = pattern or "test_*.py"
    top_level_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(this_dir))
    package_tests = loader.discover(
        start_dir = this_dir, pattern = pattern, top_level_dir = top_level_dir,
    )
    standard_tests.addTests(package_tests)
    return standard_tests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Then running tests will be just as easy as `python -m your_package.test.run`.

If you want you can place `run.py` into your root directory, then just replace `this_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)` with `this_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/test/'`. Then run tests through `python -m your_package.run`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, your solution doesn't seem to work. Running your code as is leads to ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package.test'```. Trying to tweak it leads to tests passing whether `my_package` is installed or not.

Comment: @RobBlanchard Try adding `__init__.py` to all folders, including root folder, just empty files `__init__.py` are enough.

Comment: @RobBlanchard I just added to my answer a link `Try it online!`, you can test online code there. You can see that in my online examples all folders contain `__init__.py`.

Comment: @RobBlanchard Also check that your package inside `site-packages` folder of python really contains `./test/` sub-folder, I suspect that you forgot to place `./test/` folder inside your installed package.

Comment: @RobBlanchard In all production python packages `./test/` folder with tests is always located inside installed package of `sit-packages`. Place it there too, it is a good practice to have tests distributed with installed package, so that any user can always run tests later from installed folder.

Comment: As you guessed, my `test` folder isn't distributed and I would like to keep it this way. As this library is private (and compiled with Cython by the way), I don't want someone to be able to run tests with the distributed package. That's why I'm looking for a way to test the .whl in my CI.

Comment: Otherwise, your solution would be perfect. However, it is worth mentionning that I think it requires `test` to be included in `my_package` subfolder.

Comment: @RobBlanchard If you want to run tests from .whl package then you're forced to put your tests inside your packaged whl, using my solution. And if tests are inside whl then anyone in the world later can run them too. What you can do is - build two versions of whl, one including test scripts, another one without it, both whls are identical except for inclusion of test scripts. Then first version (with tests) you run on your CI server, and second version (without tests) you distribute to people.

Comment: @RobBlanchard One more variant is - you place in your whl tests outside your package (like you did in your questions Tree), then inside `setup.py` you just call `python -m ./tests/run.py` and that's it. But this way your whl will include test scripts, don't know if you're alright with this.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I specifically was looking for a way to do this without included test scripts in the whl. Since, in my case, I aimed at running tests against installed packages in my CI, I ended up modifying temporarily the `my_package` folder to `my_package_source`. Running the `unittest` commands then looks for the package into `site-packages`.

Comment: @RobBlanchard What you are asking in your updated question is impossible: you can't make your package testable outside of your local setup if you don't distribute the test files, that much is obvious! You should accept this answer, as your aposteriori modification turned your original question into an impossible one, which is unfair to Arty who spent time trying to help you.